# изменение названия класса

Tags: javascript

есть таблица, которая копируется по клику следующей функцией 
HTML

```
<div id="parent_clone">
                 <table class="parent_clone" id="hidden_change_personal_data_address">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="personal_area_block1">        
                            <div class="contact_block_title">Delivery address 1:</div>
                        </td>               
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="personal_area_block1 inner_block_left">        
                            <div class="">country</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_area_block2">                          
                          <input type="text" name="new_country" id="new_data" class="left_info" value="" />                            
                        </td>                 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner_block_left">        
                            <div class="">province state</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_area_block2">
                          <input type="text" name="new_state" id="new_data" class="left_info" value="" />                            
                        </td>                 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner_block_left">        
                            <div class="">city</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_area_block2">
                          <input type="text" name="new_city" id="new_data" class="left_info" value="" />                          
                        </td>                 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner_block_left">        
                            <div class="">street</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_area_block2">
                          <input type="text" name="new_street" id="new_data" class="left_info" value="" />                            
                        </td>                 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner_block_left">        
                            <div class="">house </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_area_block2">
                          <input type="text" name="new_house" id="new_data" class="left_info" value="" />                           
                        </td>                 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner_block_left">        
                            <div class="">apartment </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_area_block2">
                          <input type="text" name="new_apartment" id="new_data" class="left_info" value="" />                    
                        </td>                 
                    </tr>
                </table> 
                </div>
               <!----  hidden add address table placce here ------>   







                <table class="personal_data" id="add_address_table">  
                    <tr>                    
                        <td class="personal_area_block1">                    
                            <div class="contact_block_title">Add the address</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_area_block2">
                             <img src="images/personal_cabinet/plus.png" id="add_address" />
                        </td>                         
                    </tr>                  
                    <tr>

                        <td class="personal_area_block1">                    
                            <div class="contact_block_title"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_cabinet_buttons">
                             <input type="submit" class="button_confirm" id="button_save" name="contact_sent" value="Save" />
                             <input type="submit" class="button_confirm" id="button_cancel" name="contact_sent" value="Cancel" />
                        </td>                         
                    </tr>                                 
                </table>
```

JS

```
var cloneDiv = document.getElementById('parent_clone');
var cloneTable = document.getElementById('hidden_change_personal_data_address');
 var addAddressButton = document.getElementById('add_address'); 
 addAddressButton.addEventListener('click',function(){    
       var copy = cloneTable.cloneNode(true);
       var element = document.getElementsByClassName('parent_clone');
       for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
            element[i].className = 'parent_clone' +'[i+1]';            
            };
       cloneDiv.insertBefore(copy,cloneTable.nextSibling);       
    },true)
```

но в цикле нужно поменять название класса, в зависимости от порядкового номера
Т.е 1 таблица `class="parent_clone"`, вторая `class="parent_clone2"` и т.д. в зависимости от того сколько добавляем блоков. В примере ошибка в строке

```
element[i].className = 'parent_clone' +'[i+1]';
```

Comment: `'parent_clone' +(i+1)`

Comment: в таком случае получится class = "parent_clone1"  для каждого блока

Comment: почему же? `i` же меняется в цикле

Comment: вот именно почему.
попробовал Ваш вариант , всё равно счетчик не увеличивает значение i

Comment: добавьте пример на jsfiddle, или тут в сниппете, а так же добавьте ваш html

Comment: хотя да, догадываюсь в чем ошибка :-) но нужен пример html.

Comment: добавил хтмл в пример

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('parent_clone')` вернет так же и `<table class="parent_clone" id="hidden_change_personal_data_address">`

Comment: не знаю почему , но этот цикл меняет значение только [0] элемента

Comment: проверьте значение: `element.length`

Comment: оно всегда  == 1 почему то

Comment: Минутку, сейчас попробую в ответе рассказать все :-) если никто не опередит :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбранный подход не совсем верный:

Так как после копирования элемента с классом `parent_clone` его не добавили в дом, то вызвав функцию `document.getElementsByClassName('parent_clone');` получим только один элемент который был до этого:

```
<table class="parent_clone" id="hidden_change_personal_data_address">
```

далее у него меняется класс на `parent_clone1`, а скопированный элемент с классом `parent_clone` добавлялся после.

Далее мы опять копируем элемент `id="hidden_change_personal_data_address"` у которого класс уже `parent_clone1` выбираем предыдущий вставленный элемент с классом `parent_clone`, а он все еще один на странице - меняем ему класс на `parent_clone1` и вставляем копированный див после него.

Собственно далее просто копируется див `id="hidden_change_personal_data_address"` у которого класс `parent_clone1` и спокойно вставляется, в цикл даже не заходя.

---

Решений может быть несколько, самое простое, так как вставляется по одному диву - не нужно выбирать все и менять им классы, достаточно хранить счетчик между вызовами клика и устанавливать класс копированному элементу

```
var addAddressButton = document.getElementById('add_address'); 
var i = 0;
addAddressButton.addEventListener('click',function(){    
    var copy = cloneTable.cloneNode(true);
        copy.className = 'parent_clone' +(++i);            
    cloneDiv.insertBefore(copy,cloneTable.nextSibling);       
},true)
```

Comment: понимал что дело в цикле, но не додумался, что дело в его отсутствии. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @ddeadlink на самом деле с циклом тоже могло получиться, если бы у **всех** был этот класс `parent_clone`, и он не заменялся бы на конкретный, а оставался, например `parent_clone parent_clone1` и т.д. Но смысла в этом особо нет, так как просто будут переопределяться уже назначенные элементы на то же самое, так сказать искусственное замедление :-)

Answer (score 0):

Эти строки, по сути, вообще ничего не делают.

```
for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
    element[i].className = 'parent_clone' +'[i+1]';            
}
```

Ниже правильный и работающий код.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var cloneDiv = document.getElementById('parent_clone');
  var cloneTable = document.getElementById('hidden_change_personal_data_address');
  var addAddressButton = document.getElementById('add_address');
  var count = 1; 
  addAddressButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    var cp = cloneTable.cloneNode(true);
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('parent_clone');
    cloneTable.className = 'parent_clone' +count;
    cloneDiv.insertBefore(cp,cloneTable.nextSibling);
    count++;   
  },true);
};
```

```html
<div id="parent_clone">
                 <table class="parent_clone" id="hidden_change_personal_data_address">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="personal_area_block1">        
                            <div class="contact_block_title">Delivery address 1:</div>
                        </td>               
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="personal_area_block1 inner_block_left">        
                            <div class="">country</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_area_block2">                          
                          <input type="text" name="new_country" id="new_data" class="left_info" value="" />                            
                        </td>                 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner_block_left">        
                            <div class="">province state</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_area_block2">
                          <input type="text" name="new_state" id="new_data" class="left_info" value="" />                            
                        </td>                 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner_block_left">        
                            <div class="">city</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_area_block2">
                          <input type="text" name="new_city" id="new_data" class="left_info" value="" />                          
                        </td>                 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner_block_left">        
                            <div class="">street</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_area_block2">
                          <input type="text" name="new_street" id="new_data" class="left_info" value="" />                            
                        </td>                 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner_block_left">        
                            <div class="">house </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_area_block2">
                          <input type="text" name="new_house" id="new_data" class="left_info" value="" />                           
                        </td>                 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner_block_left">        
                            <div class="">apartment </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_area_block2">
                          <input type="text" name="new_apartment" id="new_data" class="left_info" value="" />                    
                        </td>                 
                    </tr>
                </table> 
                </div>
               <!----  hidden add address table placce here ------>   







                <table class="personal_data" id="add_address_table">  
                    <tr>                    
                        <td class="personal_area_block1">                    
                            <div class="contact_block_title">Add the address</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_area_block2">
                             <img src="images/personal_cabinet/plus.png" id="add_address" />
                        </td>                         
                    </tr>                  
                    <tr>

                        <td class="personal_area_block1">                    
                            <div class="contact_block_title"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="personal_cabinet_buttons">
                             <input type="submit" class="button_confirm" id="button_save" name="contact_sent" value="Save" />
                             <input type="submit" class="button_confirm" id="button_cancel" name="contact_sent" value="Cancel" />
                        </td>                         
                    </tr>                                 
                </table>
```

Comment: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined ошибка, с учетом того что var emelent задан

Comment: принцип ясен, спасибо

Comment: тут неправильный count, т.к.  меняется имя класса 1го элемента.
То есть parent_clone меняется на parent_clone1 при первом клике , на parent_clone2 при втором и тд.

Comment: я до вас донес принцип работы, а совершенствовать код никто не запрещает.

Answer (score 0):

а так `element[i].className = 'parent_clone' +[i+1];`

Comment: этот код аналогичен приведенному мной в первом комментарии